# Function reads np.array - produces the mean for k nn to number p in np.array

Tags: python, function, numpy, knn, nearest-neighbor

I need to defina a function which reads a numpy array and produces the mean for k nearest points to number p in the array.

Example:

```
array= np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 50, 24, 32, 9, 11, 12, 10])
p= 15 (**Note this is not a number in the array, I will need to find the 
number closest to p or p number itself)
k = 3

In this case, I would need to generate the mean for ([11, 12, 10)]
as they are closest to p = 15
```

With the above numbers, I will need to find the mean for k number of points closest to p and p can be explicitly stated in the array or may not be.

I am new and very confused at this point and feel I have exhausted my resources. I feel this question has been asked before but the answers are much too complex for what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is this an assignment? What sorts of things are you suppose to be using? In this very trivial case, you should start by breaking the problem down bit by bit. Find the distance from `p` for every value in `array`, perhaps create a *new array* with those values, then sort that new array, and take the first three values...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a (1d) array `arr` and scalar input `p`, here's how you could find the mean of the `n` nearest values:

```
def neighbor_mean(arr, p, n=3):
    idx = np.abs(arr - p).argsort()[:n]
    return arr[idx].mean()

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 50, 24, 32, 9, 11, 12, 10])
neighbor_mean(arr, p=15)
# 11.0
```

In the above, first you take the absolute differences:

```
np.abs(arr - 15)
# array([14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8, 35,  9, 17,  6,  4,  3,  5])
```

Then `argsort()` returns the *indices that would sort an array*.  We're interested in the `n`-smallest absolute differences.  This is what you're really looking for, rather than sorting the differences directly.

```
np.abs(arr - p).argsort()[:3]
# array([12, 11, 13])
```

Lastly you want to index your input array `arr` and take the mean of this:

```
arr[[12, 11, 13]]
# array([12, 11, 10])  # mean: 11.0
```